# Are SOLR Cassandra queries expected to be exhaustive?

Tags: solr, cassandra

Imagine I have a hypothetical Cassandra query:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID from ACCOUNTS WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=1234;
```

You are guaranteed to get 1 and only 1 result.

Now imagine I have a SOLR query in my Cassandra query:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID from ACCOUNTS WHERE solr_query='{"q":"{!tuple}marketingcategory:secondtier"}'
```

There are 11 `ACCOUNT_ID`s that could return for this query.

Is it possible that I could get only 10? Ie is the nature of a `solr_query` that it is *non-exhaustive*?

My question is: **Are SOLR Cassandra queries expected to be exhaustive?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, DSE Search queries are returning 10 rows.  From the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/siQuerySyntax.html#siQuerySyntax):

> CQL Solr queries are defaulted to an equivalent of LIMIT 10.

You can add the `LIMIT N` clause to get more results.